Pretesting traffic on a website
I had a php application last year that was working on shared hosting that has 1 GB RAM and 1 CPU core. At the time, there were 200 users using the service and the performance was perfectly fine. However, this year in the same event with same number of users, I have exactly the same code on VPS with 3 GB RAM and 3 CPU cores, but the server crashes which drove me crazy.
My question is: is there any tool or technology that can simulate a specific number of users access the same website at the same time to mimic the actual event beforehand.
Thank you

Apache Benchmark Tool can be used,but may cause harm to your server, so be careful not to overuse it.

Does this answer your question? How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?
